# How do I calculate the distance between 2 unmeasured points in a cloud?

Tags: geometry

I know that different kinds of clouds exist at different altitudes.  If I am looking at two points in a given cloud at a given altitude, how do I determine the distance between these two visual points?

Comment: If you know altitude, angular distance will easily give you metric distance, and angle is easy to measure from ground.